# Hide Xdebug panel from Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, xdebug

I've installed Xdebug package on my Sublime 3.
Debugging works just fine, but I can't get rid of the Xdebug panel on the bottom...

Pressing Esc does nothing. When I have the Find panel oppend, just pressing Esc makes it go away, but it doesn't work with the Xdebug panel, any help?

I've found this [Sublime Text 3 - Xdebug Context panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41077670/sublime-text-3-xdebug-context-panel) here, but it does not have any answers yet...

[image]

Answer (score 17):

I had this problem and I solved it by clicking on the following options:

View> Layout> Single

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the following way:

1. Stop debugging - in Sublime's main menu: `Tools > XDebug > Stop debugging`
2. `Tools > XDebug > Restore Layout` (it's important to stop debugging first!)

If you just switch to Single Layout, 4 inactive debug tabs will remain open.